# Как заштриховать\замостить произвольную область C#

Tags: c#, graphics

Есть произвольная область заданая GraphicsPath (по сути описывающий многоугольник), эту область необходимо заштриховать линями. А лучше замостить одним и тем же изображением. 
Подобного метода в graphics я не нашел.

Пока есть такая мысль: в отдельном битмапе замостить все изображением нужным тайлом, а потом "зафилить" инвертированую область прозрачным цветом... но честно говоря - по моему это бред..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchbrush.aspx-)

*upd*

Для линий:

- [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Pen.DashCap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.dashcap.aspx)
- [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Pen.DashOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.dashoffset.aspx)
- [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Pen.DashPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.dashpattern.aspx)
- [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Pen.DashStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.dashstyle.aspx)

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо, а есть что либо подобное для линий (ожидаемый HatchPen не увидел =) )

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо, вы спасли кучу времени и спасли меня от говнокода =)